# Lattice diagram of $Z_2$x$Z_4$

Tags: group-theory

I find the order of elements, and i predict the number of subgroups is..

order1=1, order2=3, order4=3, order8=1.

I draw up that, but i think the lattice is not.....

What is the lattice diagram of $Z_2$ x $Z_4$?

Comment: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C2xC4.html

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Not all the subgroups are cyclic.  Plus, some of the elements you listed are in the same cyclic subgroup.

Comment: @Crawl What does Z_2 x Z_4 mean? . (Asking for another problem..)